# Breaking ties in tournament (order by subquery)

Tags: mysql, sql

In a hockey results database I've got a table that stores statistics for each team in each game. For each match there are (usually) two entries - one for each team. The entries store team_id, match_id and the performance of the team in that match - points earned, goals scored and many other stats that are not relevant here.

Here is the approximate query to build the tournament table:

```
SELECT  team_id, 
        COUNT(match_id) AS total_matches,
        SUM(goals_for) AS total_goals_for, 
        SUM(points) AS total_points
FROM    match_teams
WHERE   match_id IN ([match IDs here])
GROUP BY team_id
ORDER BY total_points DESC;
```

I select all entries for matches that belong in a tournament and sum points for each team then sorting by the points.

The problem is that the tie breaking rules are quite complex. Let's consider the rule "if multiple teams are tied order by points earned in games between those team".

So, if total_points is the same for teams with team_id IN (16,25,36), I should order them by something like this:

```
SELECT  teamA.team_id,
        SUM(teamA.points) AS total_points_inbetween
FROM    match_teams as teamA 
    JOIN match_teams as teamB
    ON teamA.match_id = teamB.match_id 
        AND teamA.team_id <> teamB.team_id
WHERE   teamA.match_id IN ([match IDs here])
    AND teamA.id IN (16,25,36)
    AND teamB.id IN (16,25,36)
GROUP BY teamA.team_id
ORDER BY total_points_inbetween DESC;
```

How do I include such a tie-breaker in the ORDER BY clause in the first query? I might also want another rule after that like `ORDER BY total_points DeSC, [complicated_rule_1], total_goals_for DESC, [complicated_rule_2]`

## Example

The following matches are played:

```
Match 10: team100 vs team200  2-1
Match 12: team100 vs team300  3-0
Match 15: team100 vs team400  1-2
Match 61: team100 vs team500  2-0
Match 62: team200 vs team300  5-1
Match 63: team200 vs team400  2-1
Match 66: team200 vs team500  0-3
Match 70: team300 vs team400  4-0
Match 73: team300 vs team500  5-1
Match 77: team400 vs team500  2-1
```

The following entries in match_teams represent the results:

```
match_id    team_id     goals_for   points
10          100         2           3
10          200         1           0
12          100         3           3
12          300         0           0
15          100         1           0
15          400         2           3
61          100         2           3
61          500         0           0
62          200         5           3
62          300         1           0
63          200         2           3
63          400         1           0
66          200         0           0
66          500         3           3
70          300         4           3
70          400         0           0
73          300         5           3
73          500         1           0
77          400         2           3
77          500         1           0
```

If we now count the total points (first query) for each of the teams, here are the results:

```
team_id     total_points
100         9
200         6
300         6
400         6
500         3
```

The middle 3 teams all have  the same amount of points therefore the tie has to be broken by the games between them. Here are those:

```
Match 62: team200 vs team300  5-1
Match 63: team200 vs team400  2-1
Match 70: team300 vs team400  4-0
```

And these are the corresponding entries in the database that should be taken into account for breaking tie:

```
match_id    team_id     goals_for   points
62          200         5           3
62          300         1           0
63          200         2           3
63          400         1           0
70          300         4           3
70          400         0           0
```

In games between these teams the team200 got two wins (6 points), team300 won one match (3 points) and team400 won nothing. So they should be ordered using these points and team200 > team300 > team400.

Comment: can you add some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: @vkp I edited the question to include an example.

Comment: I guess my main problem is - how can the second ordering rule be a SELECT that refers to the rows that were tied by the first rule? Because I need to "if some teams are tied, select the matches where both of the teams are among the tied".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reuse the results with temporary tables:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_match_teams;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_match_teams
    SELECT m1.*, m2.team_id AS opponent_id
    FROM match_teams m1
    JOIN match_teams m2 ON m2.match_id = m1.match_id AND m2.team_id <> m1.team_id
    WHERE m1.match_id IN (10,12,15,61,62,63,66,70,73,77);

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_result1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_result1
    SELECT  team_id, 
            COUNT(match_id) AS total_matches,
            SUM(goals_for) AS total_goals_for, 
            SUM(points) AS total_points
    FROM    tmp_match_teams
    GROUP BY team_id;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_result2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_result2 SELECT team_id, total_points FROM tmp_result1;

SELECT r1.*, SUM(m.points) AS total_points_tie
FROM tmp_result1 r1
LEFT JOIN tmp_result2 r2 
    ON  r2.total_points = r1.total_points
    AND r2.team_id <> r1.team_id
LEFT JOIN tmp_match_teams m
   ON  m.team_id = r1.team_id
   AND m.opponent_id = r2.team_id
GROUP BY r1.team_id
ORDER BY r1.total_points DESC, total_points_tie DESC, r1.total_goals_for DESC;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/HXPXRX93310

`tmp_match_teams` is a copy of `match_teams` filtered by the tournaments match_ids, so we won't need to add that condition multiple times later. It also contains the `oppenent_id`, which we will need to join "tied" teams.

`tmp_result1` contains the result of your original query.

`tmp_result2` contains the copy of `team_id, total_points` from `tmp_result1`. We need it to "join" the teams on `total_score`, and we can't use the same temporary table twice in one statement (MySQL limitation).

In the final query we "join" the teams with equal `total_score` and the corresponding matches to sum the points collected in matches between those teams. That sum is then used in the ORDER BY clause. You can also add `SUM(goals_for) AS total_goals_tie` and use it as the fourth column to sort.

If you for some reason can not use temporary tables, you can replace them with the corresponding subqueries. Then you might end with something like this:

```
SELECT r1.*, SUM(m1.points) AS total_points_tie
FROM (
    SELECT  team_id, 
            COUNT(match_id) AS total_matches,
            SUM(goals_for) AS total_goals_for, 
            SUM(points) AS total_points
    FROM    match_teams
    WHERE match_id IN (10,12,15,61,62,63,66,70,73,77)
    GROUP BY team_id
) r1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT team_id, SUM(points) AS total_points
    FROM  match_teams
    WHERE match_id IN (10,12,15,61,62,63,66,70,73,77)
    GROUP BY team_id
) r2 
    ON  r2.total_points = r1.total_points
    AND r2.team_id <> r1.team_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT m1.team_id, m1.points, m2.team_id AS opponent_id
    FROM match_teams m1
    JOIN match_teams m2 ON m2.match_id = m1.match_id AND m2.team_id <> m1.team_id
    WHERE m1.match_id IN (10,12,15,61,62,63,66,70,73,77)
) m1
    ON  m1.team_id = r1.team_id
    AND m1.opponent_id = r2.team_id
GROUP BY r1.team_id
ORDER BY r1.total_points DESC, total_points_tie DESC, r1.total_goals_for DESC
```

You can also replace the temporary tables with subqueries stored in variables in your application language. For example in PHP it might be something like this:

```
$sub_match_teams = "
    SELECT m1.*, m2.team_id AS opponent_id
    FROM match_teams m1
    JOIN match_teams m2 ON m2.match_id = m1.match_id AND m2.team_id <> m1.team_id
    WHERE m1.match_id IN (10,12,15,61,62,63,66,70,73,77)
";

$sub_result = "
    SELECT  team_id, 
            COUNT(match_id) AS total_matches,
            SUM(goals_for) AS total_goals_for, 
            SUM(points) AS total_points
    FROM    ({$sub_match_teams}) m
    GROUP BY team_id
";

$final_query = "
    SELECT r1.*, SUM(m.points) AS total_points_tie
    FROM ({$sub_result}) r1
    LEFT JOIN ({$sub_result}) r2 
        ON  r2.total_points = r1.total_points
        AND r2.team_id <> r1.team_id
    LEFT JOIN ({$sub_match_teams}) m
       ON  m.team_id = r1.team_id
       AND m.opponent_id = r2.team_id
    GROUP BY r1.team_id
    ORDER BY r1.total_points DESC, total_points_tie DESC, r1.total_goals_for DESC
";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really really really need to write a single SQL statement, which most of the times is not necessary...

Here is a copy-paste version that you may use.

But be sure to test and verify. I've just checked a few simple cases:

```
   select a.team_id, 
        sum(a.points) sort_criteria_1, /* points */
        (
           select sum(c.points)
              from match_teams c
              where c.team_id = a.team_id
                 and c.match_id in 
                    (
                       select d.match_id
                          from match_teams d
                          where d.team_id in
                             (
                                select e.team_id 
                                   from match_teams e
                                   where  e.team_id in (select f.team_id from match_teams f group by f.team_id having sum(f.points) = sum(a.points))
                                      and e.team_id <> a.team_id
                             )
                    )
        ) sort_criteria_2, /* points between */
        (
           select sum(c.goals_for)
              from match_teams c
              where c.team_id = a.team_id
                 and c.match_id in
                    (
                       select d.match_id
                          from match_teams d
                          where d.team_id in
                             (
                                select e.team_id 
                                   from match_teams e
                                   where  e.team_id in (select f.team_id from match_teams f group by f.team_id having sum(f.points) = sum(a.points))
                                      and e.team_id <> a.team_id
                             )
                    )
        ) sort_criteria_3 /* scores between */
  from match_teams a
  group by a.team_id
  order by sort_criteria_1 desc, sort_criteria_2 desc, sort_criteria_3 desc;
```

PS: Yes, I hate capital letters in coding. It is better to capitalize for only the things that needs to be emphasized. And in SQL it is unnecessary to capitalize the tokens.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your first remark? Would you say it would be better to just sort on the application side? Or detect ties on application and then break ties using a separate query?

Comment: For using big, nested SQLs:
 
Pros: 
   - Once they are written, you can use them as if you are querying a single table at application side. It makes your code at application side, clean and straight forward.
   - It makes application servers' job easier by delegating the heavy load to persistent (database) layer.
Cons:
    -  If your database server is under heavy load risk, adding heavy queries may force you to redesign the code as a whole.
    - It may cause performance problems if their execution plans somehow suddenly change.
    - Understanding nested sql's is usually harder.

Comment: So for your case, I would suggest:

To go for my example if you or some other developer will not touch that data retrieval part frequently and if your target match_points table will not have millions of rows. It makes your life at application side easier. (I assumed you were in this situation).

But if there will be millions of rows or in the future your code's related part will change frequently or your database server is not strong enough, then detect the ties and handle them separately at application side.

Hope this helps...

Kaplan

Answer (score 1):

First your query will give this:

```sql
    team_id     total_points
    100         9
    200         6
    300         6
    400         6
    500         3
```

so what you need is to know what are the teams that have the 
same sum of points to check the result of the matches between them
this query should do it.

```sql
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
    (
     SELECT  
            team_id, 
            COUNT(match_id) AS total_matches,
            SUM(goals_for) AS total_goals_for, 
            SUM(points) AS total_points
     FROM    match_teams
    -- WHERE   match_id IN ([match IDs here])
     GROUP BY team_id
    ) q1 LEFT JOIN
    (
     SELECT  
            team_id as same_ranking_team_id, 
            SUM(points) AS total_points
     FROM    match_teams
     -- WHERE   match_id IN ([match IDs here])
     GROUP BY team_id
    )q2 on q1.total_points = q2.total_points and q1.team_id != q2.same_ranking_team_id
```

this should give you this:

```
    team_id     total_points     total_points    same_ranking_team_id
    100         9                null            null
    200         6                6               300
    200         6                6               400
    300         6                6               200
    300         6                6               400
    400         6                6               200
    400         6                6               300
    500         3                null            null
```

now what we need is to know the ids of matched between thous team
to calculate the sum of points in that match

```sql
    SELECT
       *
     FROM 
     (
     SELECT  
            team_id, 
            COUNT(match_id) AS total_matches,
            SUM(goals_for) AS total_goals_for, 
            SUM(points) AS total_points
     FROM    match_teams
    -- WHERE   match_id IN ([match IDs here])
     GROUP BY team_id
    ) q1 LEFT JOIN
    (
     SELECT  
            team_id as same_ranking_team_id, 
            SUM(points) AS total_points
     FROM    match_teams
     -- WHERE   match_id IN ([match IDs here])
     GROUP BY team_id
    )q2 on q1.total_points = q2.total_points and q1.team_id != q2.same_ranking_team_id
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        select 
             match_id,
             MIN(team_id) as first_team_id,
             MAX(team_id) as second_team_id
            from match_teams
         -- WHERE   match_id IN ([match IDs here])
            group by match_id
        ) q3 on LEAST(q1.team_id, q2.same_ranking_team_id) = q3.first_team_id and GREATEST(q1.team_id, q2.same_ranking_team_id) = q3.second_team_id
```

and this should give you:

```sql
    team_id     total_points     total_points    same_ranking_team_id    match_id      frs_team     scd_team
    100         9                null            null                     null         null          null
    200         6                6               300                      62           200           300
    200         6                6               400                      63           200           400
    300         6                6               200                      62           200           300
    300         6                6               400                      70           300           400
    400         6                6               200                      63           200           400
    400         6                6               300                      70           300           400
    500         3                null            null                     null         null          null
```

now what we need is to add the points that team_id has scored on that match may later you can add goels too

```sql
    SELECT
       *
     FROM 
     (
     SELECT  
            team_id, 
            COUNT(match_id) AS total_matches,
            SUM(goals_for) AS total_goals_for, 
            SUM(points) AS total_points
     FROM    match_teams
    -- WHERE   match_id IN ([match IDs here])
     GROUP BY team_id
    ) q1 LEFT JOIN
    (
     SELECT  
            team_id as same_ranking_team_id, 
            SUM(points) AS total_points
     FROM    match_teams
     -- WHERE   match_id IN ([match IDs here])
     GROUP BY team_id
    )q2 on q1.total_points = q2.total_points and q1.team_id != q2.same_ranking_team_id
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        select 
             match_id,
             MIN(team_id) as first_team_id,
             MAX(team_id) as second_team_id
            from match_teams
         -- WHERE   match_id IN ([match IDs here])
            group by match_id
        ) q3 on LEAST(q1.team_id, q2.same_ranking_team_id) = q3.first_team_id and GREATEST(q1.team_id, q2.same_ranking_team_id) = q3.second_team_id

        LEFT JOIN 
        (
          select 
             match_id,
             team_id ,
             points
          from match_teams
        -- WHERE   match_id IN ([match IDs here])
        )q4 on q1.team_id = q4.team_id and q3.match_id = q4.match_id
```

this should give you this

```sql
    team_id     total_points     total_points    same_ranking_team_id    match_id      frs_team     scd_team   team_id  match_id  points
    100         9                null            null                     null         null          null      null      null     null
    200         6                6               300                      62           200           300       200       62        3
    200         6                6               400                      63           200           400       200       63        3
    300         6                6               200                      62           200           300       300       62        0
    300         6                6               400                      70           300           400       300       70        3
    400         6                6               200                      63           200           400       400       63        0
    400         6                6               300                      70           300           400       400       70        0
    500         3                null            null                     null         null          null      null      null     null
```

now you have all data to classify you teams the final query is like this:

```sql
    SELECT
       q1.team_id,
       q1.total_points,
       sum(COALESCE(q4.points, 0)) as teis_points
    FROM 
     (
     SELECT  
            team_id, 
            COUNT(match_id) AS total_matches,
            SUM(goals_for) AS total_goals_for, 
            SUM(points) AS total_points
     FROM    match_teams
    -- WHERE   match_id IN ([match IDs here])
     GROUP BY team_id
    ) q1 LEFT JOIN
    (
     SELECT  
            team_id as same_ranking_team_id, 
            SUM(points) AS total_points
     FROM    match_teams
     -- WHERE   match_id IN ([match IDs here])
     GROUP BY team_id
    )q2 on q1.total_points = q2.total_points and q1.team_id != q2.same_ranking_team_id
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        select 
             match_id,
             MIN(team_id) as first_team_id,
             MAX(team_id) as second_team_id
            from match_teams
         -- WHERE   match_id IN ([match IDs here])
            group by match_id
        ) q3 on LEAST(q1.team_id, q2.same_ranking_team_id) = q3.first_team_id and GREATEST(q1.team_id, q2.same_ranking_team_id) = q3.second_team_id

        LEFT JOIN 
        (
          select 
             match_id,
             team_id ,
             points
          from match_teams
        -- WHERE   match_id IN ([match IDs here])
        )q4 on q1.team_id = q4.team_id and q3.match_id = q4.match_id

        group by q1.team_id, q1.total_points
        order by q1.total_points desc, teis_points desc
```

and this shoud give you

```sql
    team_id     total_points     teis_points  
    100         9                0
    200         6                6 
    300         6                3
    400         6                0
    500         3                0
```

Hope i didnot miss a thing here.

to test my answer :

```sql
    drop table match_teams;

    create table match_teams(
    match_id int,
    team_id int,
    goals_for int,
    points int
    );

    insert into match_teams values
    (10,100,2,3),(10,200, 1, 0),(12,100, 3, 3),
    (12,300, 0, 0),(15,100, 1, 0),(15,400, 2, 3),
    (61,100, 2, 3),(61,500, 0, 0),(62,200, 5, 3),
    (62,300, 1, 0),(63,200, 2 ,3),(63,400, 1 ,0),
    (66,200, 0 ,0),(66,500, 3 ,3),(70,300, 4 ,3),
    (70,400, 0 ,0),(73,300, 5 ,3),(73,500, 1 ,0),
    (77,400, 2 ,3),(77,500, 1 ,0);
```